# Understanding declval function a little further

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, declval

I just learn the declval keyword in c++ and I was wondering why in the following code `(std::add_rvalue_reference<Foo>::type).constFunc7() x = 3;` is not compiling. Isn't it the same thing as `decltype(declvalCustom<Foo>().constFunc7()) y = 3;` with the template declaration of `declvalCustom`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    int constFunc7() { return 7; }
};

template< class T >
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declvalCustom();

std::add_rvalue_reference<Foo> helper();

int main()
{
    // decltype(helper().constFunc7()); // not working
    // (std::add_rvalue_reference<Foo>::type).constFunc7() x = 3; // not working
    decltype(declvalCustom<Foo>().constFunc7()) y = 3; // ok
    decltype(std::declval<Foo>().constFunc7()) z = 3; // ok
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. `main` returns `int`, not `void`; 2. `std::add_rvalue_reference<Foo>::type` is a type, so how can you think you call a member function on it?

Comment: Did you mean `decltype` keyword? `std::declval` fundamentally is a function, even if it cannot be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`declval` is not a keyword. `std::declval` is a function template, that can only legally appear in unevaluated contexts. Your `declValCustom` is also a function template with similar properties.

`std::add_rvalue_reference<Foo>::type` is a type, not an expression, so you can't use it as a subexpression.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If the problem is that `std::add_rvalue_reference<Foo>::type` is a type and not an expression, why doesn't it work with the `helper()` expression?

Comment: `std::add_rvalue_reference<Foo> helper();` declares a function of 0 arguments which returns `std::add_rvalue_reference<Foo>`, so `helper()` is an expression of type `std::add_rvalue_reference<Foo>`, which is a trait type, not `Foo &&`, in particular it doesn't have a member function `constFunc7`. You are missing `::type` from the declaration of `helper`